# Pythonic way to convert Pandas dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file, which I then convert to a Pandas dataframe called `stocks`.  The `stocks` dataframe is in wide format and I'd like to convert it to long format.

Here's what the `stocks` dataframe looks like after it's ingested and converted from JSON:

```
    TSLA     MSFT     GE      DELL 
0   993.22   320.72   93.19   57.25
```

I would like to convert the `stocks` dataframe into the following format:

```
     ticker   price
0    TSLA     993.22  
1    MSFT     320.72
2    GE       93.19
3    DELL     57.25
```

Here is my attempt (which works):

```
stocks = pd.read_json('stocks.json', lines=True).T.reset_index()
stocks.columns = ['ticker', 'price']
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` provides the [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function for this job.

```py
pd.melt(stocks, var_name="ticker", value_name="price")
```

```py
#  ticker   price
#0   TSLA  993.22
#1   MSFT  320.72
#2     GE   93.19
#3   DELL   57.25
```

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps more intuitive method than `melt` would be to transpose and reset the index:

```
df = df.T.reset_index().set_axis(['ticker', 'price'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  ticker   price
0   TSLA  993.22
1   MSFT  320.72
2     GE   93.19
3   DELL   57.25
```

Edit: oops, saw that the OP already did that! :)